# Matplotlib draw regressor line in 3d

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I'm trying to draw a line in 3d but it hasn't been working out. I am able to get a proper scatter done, like you can see in this picture.  [image: scatter]

When I'm actually drawing a line through it I'm getting the following error: 'ValueError: input operand has more dimensions than allowed by the axis remapping'

Any idea how to solve this?

My code:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Path of file
path = Path("data/houses.csv")

df = pd.read_csv(path)


# Assign X and Y axis
X = df[['GarageArea', 'YearBuilt']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
y = df[['SalePrice']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=1)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print(r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
print(X_test['GarageArea'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X['GarageArea'], X['YearBuilt'], y, c='blue', marker='o')
ax.plot(X_test['GarageArea'], X_test['YearBuilt'], y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)
# set your labels
ax.set_xlabel('Garage Area')
ax.set_ylabel('Year Built')
ax.set_zlabel('Price')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a minimal working example by uploading `data/house.csv`, and also provide the full tracing stack of the error.

The error message you see should come from `ax.plot`, and more specifically on the line

```
zs = np.broadcast_to(zs, np.shape(xs))
```

which is line 1570 of `mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py`.

`X_test['GarageArea']` and `X_test['YearBuilt']` are two pandas **Series**, which means they are 1-D array and has the shape of **(N,)**. `y_predict` is the output of `model.predict`. [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` is able to train on multiple targets simultaneously](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), although in your example you have only one target which is the *SalePrice*, so its output is a matrix of shape `(n_samples, n_targets)`, or **(N,1)**, something like `[[1],[2],[3],...]`.

`Axes3D.plot` can take input of (xs, ys, zs, ...). For some reason the author of `Axes3D.plot` decided that zs should be

- either of the same shape of xs and ys,
- or a single value

so that same z will be associated with all (xs, ys), and `np.broadcast_to` is used to handle both cases. In the first case, the `broadcast_to` does not take effect, and for the second case, an array of same shape of xs and ys will be created with value of zs.

In your code, numpy will try to broadcast (N,1) to (N,). (N,1) means it's an array of lenth N of array of lenth 1, such as `[[1],[2],[3]]`. `broadcast_to` is similar to `repeat`, and it's impossible to repeat (N,1) to get (N,).

You can try a few more tests to understand the rule of `np.broadcast_to`:

| no | test | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | `np.broadcast_to(1,np.shape([1,2,3,4,5,6]))` | ok |
| 02 | `np.broadcast_to([1],np.shape([1,2,3,4,5,6]))` | ok |
| 03 | `np.broadcast_to([[1]],np.shape([1,2,3,4,5,6]))` | error |
| 04 | `np.broadcast_to([1,2,3],np.shape([1,2,3,4,5,6]))` | error |
| 05 | `np.broadcast_to([1,2,3,4,5,6],np.shape([1,2,3,4,5,6]))` | ok |
| 06 | `np.broadcast_to([[1,2,3,4,5,6]],np.shape([1,2,3,4,5,6]))` | error |
| 07 | `np.broadcast_to(1,np.shape([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))` | ok |
| 08 | `np.broadcast_to([1],np.shape([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))` | ok |
| 09 | `np.broadcast_to([[1]],np.shape([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))` | ok |
| 10 | `np.broadcast_to([1,2,3],np.shape([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))` | ok |
| 11 | `np.broadcast_to([[1,2,3]],np.shape([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))` | ok |
| 12 | `np.broadcast_to([[1],[2],[3]],np.shape([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))` | error |
| 13 | `np.broadcast_to([1,2],np.shape([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))` | error |
| 14 | `np.broadcast_to([1,2,3,4],np.shape([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))` | error |

In order to fix your problem, change `y_pred` (case 6) to `y_pred.flatten()` (case 5) in `ax.plot`.

An MWE attached:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

rng = np.random.default_rng()
N = 2000
yearBuilt = rng.random(N)*(2020-1860)+1860
garageArea = rng.random(N)*1000
salePrice = rng.normal(yearBuilt*1000 + garageArea*500 + (yearBuilt-1860)*garageArea/(2020-1860)/1000*300000,50000,N)
data = {
    'YearBuilt': yearBuilt,
    'GarageArea': garageArea,
    'SalePrice': salePrice
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Assign X and Y axis
X = df[['GarageArea', 'YearBuilt']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
y = df[['SalePrice']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=1)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X['GarageArea'], X['YearBuilt'], y, c='blue', marker='o')
ax.plot(X_test['GarageArea'], X_test['YearBuilt'], y_pred.flatten(), color='red', linewidth=3)
# set your labels
ax.set_xlabel('Garage Area')
ax.set_ylabel('Year Built')
ax.set_zlabel('Price')

plt.show()
```

[See output image of the MWE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZX6d.png)

Consider you draw your objects in a Cartesian x-y-z coordinate system. `model.predict` can be considered as a function which maps an array of (GarageArea, YearBuilt) another array. `X_test` is a set of randomly selected and ordered points on the x-y plane, and `model.predict` will calculate the z coordiate. What you see will be a set of random ordered points connected like a ball of yarn.

To draw a line reflecting the linearity of your model, you need to provide the projection of the line on the x-y plane as input of `model.predict`, instead of X_test. You can use the linear regression of GarageArea as a function of YearBuilt to get that line. Another idea is to draw the linear prediction plane, or the trend plane, which is more accurate, rather than a trend line.